# Make method of class using generics be able to return both its own and its subclasses instances

Tags: java, generics, subclass

I implemented the following Java classes:

```
public class Data<T> {

    private List<T> data;

    public List<T> getData() {
        return this.data;
    }


    public Data<T> setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
        return this;
    }

    public Data<T> getAsNullIfEmpty() {
        if (this.data == null || this.data.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return this;
    }

}
```

```
public class IntegerData extends Data<Integer> {}
```

I would like the `getAsNullIfEmpty()` method to be able to be called by its subclasses instances.

The line `IntegerData integerData = new IntegerData().getAsNullIfEmpty();` throws the following compilation error:
`incompatible types: Data<java.lang.Integer> cannot be converted to IntegerData`

I tried changing the body of the method `getAsNullIfEmpty()` to this:

```
public <E extends Data<T>> E getAsNullIfEmpty() {
    if (this.data == null || this.data.isEmpty())
        return null;
    return this;
}
```

This doesn't compile though because `Data<T>` does not extend itself.
Is there a way to accomplish this without recurring to overriding the method in each of the child classes or using an explicit cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the "usual" trick for having a class's generics refer to itself, plus an unsafe cast.

```
public class Data<T, D extends Data<T, D>> {

    private List<T> data;

    public List<T> getData() {
        return this.data;
    }


    public D setData(List<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
        return (D) this;
    }

    public D getAsNullIfEmpty() {
        if (this.data == null || this.data.isEmpty())
            return null;
        return (D) this;
    }

}
public class IntegerData extends Data<Integer, IntegerData> { ... }
```

Comment: Similar version of this idea can be found in Effective Java in Item 2 which discusses builder pattern. There instead of `return (D) this;` author uses `return self();` which is calling `protected abstract D self();` with is required to be overridden in subclass as `protected [SubclassName] self(){ return this;}` (we assume that D is defined to hold subclass name).

Comment: This solution solves the problem with casting. But means also, that you will not allow direct usage of Data class like 'd = new Data<Integer>()', because you will *have* to implement a subclass for each parameter type. It is not much work, but still some overhead.

Comment: @mentallurg I think you could actually get away with `Data<Integer, ?> d = new Data<Integer, Data<Integer>>()` in this version?

Comment: No :)   `Data<Integer>` will not compile because here you have one type parameter instead of two.

Comment: Hmmm.  And `Data<Integer, ?> d = new Data<Integer, Data<Integer, ?>>()`?